# animation wont work on <span>

Tags: html, css, css-animations

So I am trying to animate the `#txtName` class and it's working fine. My problem is the `.smallletters` is set as `<span>` property inside the `<h1>` and I can't make it to start animating outside of the page just like The `#txtName` doing. It means When I refresh I already see the `.smallletters` and then the `#txtName` is coming and pushing `.smallletters` down.

```css
#txtName {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ff6666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  animation-name: First;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes First {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}

.smallletters {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  display: inline;
  animation-name: second;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes Second {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
  <h1 id="txtName">Oded Menashe<span class="smallletters">Hair Styling</span></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: `.smallletters { display: inlne-block; }` Animation and alot of other properties cannot be applied to inline elements, which `span` is by default. Also, your animation is name `Second`(with a capital S), not `second` (which is how you are applying it).

Answer (score 1):

You can only animate `top` of positioned elements, so position your `smallletters`.  Also your animation is `Second` (note the capital s)

```css
#txtName {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ff6666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  animation-name: First;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes First {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}

.smallletters {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  display: inline;
  animation-name: Second;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  position: relative;
}

@keyframes Second {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
  <h1 id="txtName">Oded Menashe<span class="smallletters">Hair Styling</span></h1>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want exactly, but you should change two or three things, depending on what you really want:

1.) Identical spelling of animation name ("second" vs. "Second"), 2.) `position: relative` for the span, 3.) `display: inline-block` for the span

```css
#txtName {
  font-size: 80px;
  color: #ff6666;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  animation-name: First;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes First {
  0% {
    top: 10px;
  }
  50% {
    top: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}

.smallletters {
  font-size: 40px;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  animation-name: second;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes second {
  0% {
    top: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="main-header">
  <h1 id="txtName">Oded Menashe<span class="smallletters">Hair Styling</span></h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Upvoted but inline or inline-block makes no difference, it's the positioning that matters

Comment: @Pete inline-block makes no difference for the animation, but for the way that text is displayed in relation to the rest of its container at certain widths, that's why I added it.

Answer (score 0):

`span` tags are `display: inline` by default, and so will ignore positional instructions (margin, top, left etc).

Give it `display: block` or `inline-block` if you want to apply (or animate) these properties.